# USB 3 Hub to drive dual monitors from Laptop @ 2560 x 1440

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, usb-hub

Taking this [USB 3.0 Docking Station with Dual DVI/HDMI/VGA Video (sd3500v)](http://www.kensington.com/kensington/en/no/p/1504/K33972EU/usb-3-0-docking-station-with-dual-dvi-hdmi-vga-video-%28sd3500v%29.aspx)
 as an example.

I'm trying to find out what hardware configuration/spec a laptop would require to allow it to drive two Dell U2711 @ 2560 x 1440

Not too worried about specific laptops, more what ports (and protocol versions)n and graphics card would be required to run this setup.

Again not bothered if the laptop screen must mirror one of the monitors.  Ideally, I'd plug into the hub close the laptop lid and then use the monitors and external keyboard and mouse.

Is this even possible?

TIA

EDIT:

Apologies if this is a repeated question...although if it hasn't been asked in 2013 then any answers to previously asked dups may no longer be relevant. (Happy to be proved wrong)

Comment: Any supported laptop with a USB 3.0 or 2.0 should support it.

Comment: But what would you need Graphics card wise in order to drive it?

Comment: I don't see any evidence that the device requires the host pc to have a GPU.  Contact Kensington if specific product requirements not listed on their website.

Comment: @MattC: The dock doesn't connect to your graphics card, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Try the Hootoo 7-port USB hub, that had been really useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work well. You need two HDMI 1.3 connections for those monitors, which each clock close to 10 Gbit/second. Total bandwidth would be approximately 20 Gbit/second, but USB3 is limited to 5 GBit/second.

Comment: This. Sending graphics over USB is like trying to drive a car down a telephone wire

Comment: Well, if you consider 1024x768 monitors (.8 Mpixel) instead of 2560x1440 monitors (3.6 Mpixel), 5 Gbps should do.

Comment: So, basically I need a laptop with two HDMI 1.3 ports and a graphics card(s) powerful enough to drive them at my desired res?

Comment: I think the newest MacBooks can pull this off, but they use Thunderbolt (which does clock in at the necessary 20 Gbps).

Comment: Ok what about if I dropped to 1920 x 1200 or 1080, would the above setup be viable?

Comment: @MattC: One 1920x1200 monitor via USB3 and another via HDMI should work. Still, as Jobbo points out, USB wasn't designed for this so the quality of implemenation definitely matters (on both sides, laptop and dock)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for such a product myself and found the Elgato Thunderbolt 3 Dock. It's a dock with multiple ports and supports dual 4K monitors. Your PC or Mac requires a USB-C port with Thunderbolt 3